# Write a function that takes two parameters, an array of numbers and a single number and returns true or false if the number is in the array

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong, any help would be much appreciated.

```
var array = [3, 5, 6, 10, 20];

function array (arr, num) {
    for (var i=0 ;  i < array.length; i++);
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}

arr(10);
```

Comment: `arr(10);` Your function is named `array` (which is a bad choice), not `arr`, and it expects two parameters.

Comment: It looks like you probably need to review how for loops work. Anyways, you need to have a condition that checks all the indices' values against the number parameter, you can do this for each iteration of the for loop. You should also name your functions appropriately, like what the function is actually supposed to do.

Comment: var array, function arrray, arr??? no if? You have many mistakes....

Comment: your check condition is **missing**. Also, do not use `array` as a function name

Comment: where is the IF part?

Comment: Check which `}` corresponds to which `{` and I'm sure you'll realize why your syntax is messed up.

Answer (score -1):

Use `indexOf` to check if an Object is in an `Array`. `indexOf` will return the `index` of the element if it is in the `Array` and `-1` if it is not.

```
 function arrayContains(arr, obj) {
   return arr.indexOf(obj) != -1;
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="num">
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Check if value is one of the first nine terms of the Fibonacci sequence" onClick="check()"/> 
<br/>
<span id="result"></span>
<script>
var array = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34];
function arrayContains(arr, obj) {
       return arr.indexOf(obj) != -1;
}
var result = document.getElementById("result");
function check(){
   var num = document.getElementById("num").value;
   if(num.trim().length&&!isNaN(num)){
     if(arrayContains(array, parseInt(num, 10))){
       result.innerHTML = "Number is one of the first nine terms of the Fibonacci sequence.";
     } else {
     result.innerHTML = "Number is <b>not</b> one of the first nine terms of the Fibonacci sequence.";
     }
   } else {
    result.innerHTML = "<b style='color: red;'>Input must be a number!</b>";
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

You don't really have to use a loop for that. You can use the indexOf() function. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

Your code will looks like:

```
var numbers = [3, 5, 6, 10, 20];
function isNumberInList(numbers, number) {
  var result = false;
  if(numbers.indexOf(number)!=-1){
     result = true;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: That's an awfully convoluted way of doing the exact same thing as @hev1's answer does